# Is there a way to update the Names of the report Categories?

Tags: custom-report-type, reports-api

I want to update the name of the **"Report Categories"** but I do not find any way. Is there a solution to do this. I see 2-3 ideas posted for being able to add new **"Report category"** but nothing for updating its name. Here I want to update **"Customer Support Reports"** to **"Cases"**.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There is no functionality to rename the standard folders.  (But I'm hoping someone proves me wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NOPE but there is a [popular Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007CnjAAE) to up vote